# Error ":app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug" when upgrade to new version of flutter

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart, gradlew

I upgrade flutter from v1.91. hotfix 6 by using flutter upgrade --force.

Then i build an example "layers" - flutter run, it shows this message, while if i switch to 1.91, everything built ok

[image]
flutter run --stacktrace gives this error

> Could not find an option named "stacktrace".

flutter doctor -v

> G:\new\new_exam>flutter doctor -v [√] Flutter (Channel stable,
>   v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.535],
>   locale en-US) • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at G:\Flutter\flutter
>   • Framework revision 27321eb (12 days ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
>   • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6 • Dart version 2.7.0
>
> [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
>   version 29.0.2) • Android SDK at G:\Flutter\android • Android NDK
>   location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
>   support) • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2 • ANDROID_HOME =
>   G:\Flutter\android • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = G:\Flutter\android\sdk • Java
>   binary at: G:\flutter\openjdk\bin\java • Java version OpenJDK Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_232-b09) • All Android licenses accepted.
>
> [!] Android Studio (not installed) • Android Studio not found;
>   download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html (or
>   visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
>   instructions).
>
> [!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.3) • IntelliJ at
>   C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.1 X
>   Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific
>   functionality. X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific
>   functionality. • For information about installing plugins, see
>   https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins
>
> [!] Connected device ! No devices available
>
> ! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa77H.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4DTX.png

Comment: [this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25271) might interest you, it looks like a androidx upgrade issue

Answer (score 0):

I feel the solution is pretty straight forward. Usually, it's always a best practice to use Android Studio when working with Flutter and Dart. Reasons are there are some dependencies that would require you to use Android Studio to have it work well for you, especially when you're just starting to work with Flutter and Dart.

Flutter Doctor is pretty precise as to the issues you're experiencing.

After downloading Android Studio, do the following;

1. Navigate to your Preferences or Android Studio Settings on PC, then select, Plugins, ensure the following plugins are installed.

   - Android APK Support
   - Android NDK Support
   - Dart
   - Flutter
   - EditorConfig
   - App Links Assistant
   - Google Services
   - Gradle
   - Properties Support
   - Java Bytecode Decompiler
   - Java Stream Debugger
   - Task Management
   - YAML

Among others which would be automatically installed by Android Studio for you, this should take that error away and you should be fine.

2. Then, before you probably run your App, if you see the get dependencies at the Top of your Android Studio, click the get dependencies so that Android studio can get the latest dependencies to run your App without issues.
3. Ensure you run a cold restart after each time you add a new dependency to your pubspec.yaml file.